# The no. of homomorphisms between third roots of unity and $S_3$

Tags: group-theory

Find the number of homomorphisms between $(\{1, \omega, \omega^2\}, \times)$ and $S_3$. ($\omega$ being one of the third roots of unity).

Apart from the trivial homomorphism we have another homomorphism mapping $\omega^i$ to $\sigma^i$, where $\sigma^3=1$ and $\sigma \neq 1$ in $S_3$. Just wanted to clarify are there any more.

Comment: All you need to know is how the generator $\omega$ of the cyclic group with 3 elements ($(\{1,\omega,\omega^2\},\times)$) is mapped into $S_3$.

Comment: Also, make sure to clarify that $\sigma \ne 1$.

Comment: @Batman Yup that's what I did in the exam and wrote my answer as 2. Just wanted to be sure.

Comment: $\omega \to (123)$ and $\omega \to (132)$ and $\omega \to ()$ are the 3 valid answers.

Comment: @Batman Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three, not two. In addition to the trivial element, $\omega$ can be sent to either $(123)$ or $(132)$. In your question and comments you seem to only include one of these.

Although you are mapping to the same subgroup, the maps are different. They correspond to an *[automorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism)* of the subgroup, and the cyclic group of order three has two automorphisms. Each automorphism corresponds to one of these maps.

Comment: Yes, failed to see that. Thanks for the clarification.